# nvidia-settings ImportError: No module named 'dbus'

Tags: python, nvidia-settings

I try to switch my graphics card via NVIDIA X Server Settings.

However when I click on NVIDIA:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/share/screen-resolution-extra/nvidia-prime.py", line 22, in <module>
     import sys, dbus, logging
     ImportError: No module named 'dbus'
```

I get this error. I installed dbus package. Also I tried running nvidia-prime.py manually and it run without error. Also I can import dbus without trouble. Why I get this error?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. `python-dbus` is installed, and I can run `/usr/bin/python -c "import dbus"` without an error. If I run `nvidia-settings` as root, I can switch prime-profiles without a problem.

Comment: @SlightlyCuban want to make that an answer? it worked for me to run as root.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I had another python version on my `PATH`. Removing that path entry to make sure that `python` points to `/usr/bin/python` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You say you installed "dbus package". Which one? There's `python-dbus` and `python3-dbus`. 
I found this question because I faced the same issue with another software package, and the reason was that while I did have `python-dbus` installed, I did not have `python3-dbus`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I stumbled upon a solution.

Try switching GPU using terminal. It does not give an error then.

TO SWITCH TO NVIDIA GPU:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

TO SWITCH TO INTEGRATED INTEL GPU:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```